# Instantiating single-variable "ordinary" derivatives from total derivatives

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

We've been learning total derivatives in class and I had some questions about how our "ordinary" single-variable derivatives are instantiated from all this.

Let's say we have a differentiable real-to-real function $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Just to see how everything relates, I will try to compute every "derivative-related object" that we've learned (e.g. total, ordinary, directional etc.)

By definition, the total derivative $Df(x)$ is the linear function $T : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying the following limit:
$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{|f(x+h)-f(x)-A(h)|}{|h|} = \lim_{h \to 0} |\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} - \frac{A(h)}{h}| = |\lim_{h \to 0}[\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}-\frac{A(h)}{h}]|$

$= |f'(x) - lim_{h \to 0}\frac{A(h)}{h}|$

(I believe it can be shown that for all x, $Df(x)$ exists iff $f'(x)$ exists?)

This makes it clear that, if $Df(x)$ exists, then it must be $(Df(x))(v) = f'(x)v$

The directional derivative $D_{v}f(x)$ is simply the total derivative evaluated at v i.e. $D_{v}f(x)=(Df(x))(v)=f'(x)v$

Thus we get that:
$$(1) f'(x) = Df(x)(1) = D_{1}f(x)$$ or equivalently
$$ (2) f'(x) = Df(x)(e_{1}) = D_{e_{1}}f(x)$$
where $D_{e_{1}}f(x)$ is the partial derivative of f wrt x (the only possible direction).

My questions are:

1. Is it only accidental that (1) and (2) holds or is there some special reason behind it?
2. Given that (1) and (2), is it fair to say that partial derivatives (each of which is the total derivative evaluated on vectors of the standard basis) is a true generalization of a "ordinary derivative" like $f'(x)$ in higher dimensions?

Comment: “Normal derivative” is not a very good name, since that means the derivative in the normal direction (to a surface, for example).

Comment: I see the problem. What might be a good alternative?

Comment: Ordinary derivative, perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is not accidental, but the reason is just that mathematicians defined the total derivative as something related to ordinary derivatives (and you can see this in the limit definition you gave for the total derivative). If it were something unrelated, they probably wouldn't have used the word "derivative" again. (As an aside, $-e_1$ is another direction, and then you'd get $-f'(x)$.)
2. $f'(x)=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x}f(x)=\text{[something like }Df(x)(1)\text{]}$. You might think of the standard matrix for $Df(x)$ as the $1\times1$: $[f'(x)]$. Because of this, I would say that both the partial derivative and the total derivative are "true" generalizations of the ordinary derivative.